# Can more than 100 users test beta versions of iOS apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile, testflight

I've learned that for beta testing (even through software like TestFlight) you need to sign the IPA with ad hoc provisioning profile. However, you can issue up to 100 of those. Is there a way to beta test the iOS app with more than 100 people?

As I mentioned above, we're using TestFlight and have already used all 100 ad hoc provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't using some of those devices anymore you will have the option to remove those when your iOS Developer Account comes up for renewal and can re-use those slots. Though 100 is a hard limit per account in non-enterprise settings.

If you work with different clients it's good to have them get their own account so you don't use up all 100 device slots and can use theirs instead. Otherwise a couple projects in and you'll be up to 100 pretty quickly.

Comment: We're an app developer company, so even if we don't work for different clients, we have several apps of our own. We need to have all of them under the same publisher account. Thus having 100 profiles for several apps is quite a pain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you buy enterprise developer account, you can use in-house deployment which allows you to add basically unlimited amount of users.

Comment: In-house is not really made for Beta (unless you can afford 300$/year). It's something useful for Enterprises's apps that should not be available on the AppStore

Comment: We have enterprise account. However, we wouldn't really like to distribute enterprise provisioning profile to external beta testers.